# grails-2.0.0.RC3 Using g:include is breaking g:set on page scope

Tags: grails

This issue is related to grails version 2.0.0.RC3. After I upgraded from 2.0.0.RC1 to 2.0.0.RC3 I started noticing that variables set at the page scope withing GSPs, using the g:set tag, were not working. After some investigation I realized the issue was caused by the g:include tags within the same GSP file.

I am able to reproduce the problem with the following snippet of code in a brand new grails project. After creating the project, I create a file under the views/include/head.gsp and leave it empty. Then I insert the following into the index.gsp:

```
    <g:include view="/include/head.gsp" />
    <h2>Set Test</h2>
    <g:set var="myVariable" value="${true}" />
    <g:if test="${myVariable}">
    <p>it is true</p>
    </g:if>
    <p>myVariable: '${myVariable}'</p>
```

The output from the above snippet should be:

```
    Set Test
    it is true
    myVariable: 'true'
```

But, instead what I get is the following:

```
    Set Test
    myVariable: ''
```

I am starting to think this is a bug. What do you think?

Thanks,
-Cesar

Comment: I submitted this as a [bug in the Grails JIRA](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8465).

Comment: If you think that's a bug, report it to the developer mailing list.

Comment: I did raise it as a [question on the user mailing list](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/grails-2-0-0-RC3-Using-g-include-is-breaking-g-set-on-page-scope-td4173573.html).